# When your sock(s) is / are torn

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-choice

Please imagine you have torn one of your socks and the other one (in the same pair) is OK. Which one of the following sentences is t he correct way to convey this message:

> 1. I have torn my **sock**. 
>    2. I have torn my **socks**. 
>    3. My **sock** has torn. 
>    4. My **socks** have torn.

[image]

Comment: 1 or 3. Only one sock is torn, even though you may decide to discard both. In fact, (3) may be best, because, judging by the picture, you didn't deliberately or accidentally tear your sock, it just became worn at the heel.

Comment: But I wouldn't use the "middle" form _has torn_. I was say _is torn_ (adjectival, not passive) or _has got torn_ (passive).

Comment: I don't really see a lot wrong with 'has torn', 'has ripped', etc. My pharmacist wife migght say 'the emulsion has split'.